# resource warn java

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, io, memory-leaks

Eclipse(Juno) says there is a **resource leak warnings** in this sample.
Is this valid?
This is occurred when the exception throwing point is in the `for` loop.

```
package kuni;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ResourceWarn {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            FileWriter f = null;
            try{
                f = new FileWriter("test.txt");
                for(String s : Arrays.asList("a","b","c")){
                    if(s.equals("c"))throw new RuntimeException("aa"); //resource leak warn here
                    f.write(s);
                }
            }finally{
                try{
                    f.close();
                }catch(Exception ignore){
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Resource leak: 'f' is not closed at this location

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what Eclipse is complaining about.

```
        } finally {
            try {
                System.err.println("closing f");
                f.close();
            } catch(Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
```

The problem is the `println` !!!

Eclipse thinks that it is possible that the `System.err.println(...)` call could throw an exception.  If that were to happen, then the `f.close()` call wouldn't happen .... ergo, a leak.

You and I know that this "can't happen" ... but the Eclipse code analyser probably doesn't understand the special nature of `System.err`.

And besides, it is possible that somewhere else in the code we've done something that *would* cause `System.err.println(...)` to fail; e.g. we might have used `System.setErr(...)` to replace the normal `System.err` instance with an instance of some custom `PrintWriter` subclass that throws an unchecked exception on the 2nd Tuesday of every month.

Try removing the `println` or moving it after the `close` call.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have a resource leak there. I don't know what eclipse is complaining of.

The only comments I have regarding your code are:

1. It will be easier to read if you include spaces between keywords and opening/closing braces.
2. You shouldn't throw away the IOException in the finally block, rather you should log it and continue (as you currently do). There are weird bugs that happen when cleanup code throws exceptions and logging religiously will save you extremely painful debugging sessions.
3. For a demo like this, printing the stack trace is fine, but in general you should be logging it, and only printing a short error message to stderr. Users panic when they see stacktraces, even when benign.

Other than that, the code looks good to me, and none of the above suggest a resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

When you throw a new `RuntimeException`, you are immediately lead to the `catch` block without having a chance to close your `FileWriter`. You need to close your `FileWriter` in the case a `RuntimeException` is thrown.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    FileWriter f = null;
    try {
        f = new FileWriter("test.txt");
        for (String s : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")) {
            if (s.equals("c"))
                throw new RuntimeException("aa"); // resource leak warn here
            f.write(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (f != null) {
                f.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, he is using a try/finally statement inside a try/catch statement. So the file will be closed. There isn't a resource leak; and, in a non-trivial example, keeping the file cleanup closer to the file usage is a non-trivial advantage over your recommendation.

Comment: this is good readable, the OP with nested try catch us a bit ugly